# How to use std::function in cython

Tags: c++, c++11, cython

I've seen [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) that you can do

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
```

to refer to parameters of type `std::string` and `std::vector`. I need to pass functions to a c++ method expecting `std::function<>`. I tried doing

```
from libcpp.function cimport function
```

but that didn't work:

```
from libcpp.function cimport function
^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython_topics.pyx:3:0: 'libcpp/function/function.pxd' not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    language="c++",                   # generate and compile C++ code
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 934, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1056, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: cython_topics.pyx
```

What's the right way to call a c++ function expecting `std::function<>`?

Comment: Must you use cython? You can handle that easily in C++ code, have a look at [PyObject_Call](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call).

Comment: @YiFei I have a boost-python wrapper for a fairly large c++ library. I'm experimenting with Cython to see if it it is an acceptable option for an updated wrapping platform for an updated version of the library. So, no. I don't have to use Cython, but the question is aimed to determine if Cython is capable of wrapping C++ methods which expect std::function as parameter types.

Comment: You want to call python function in C++ as std::function? Then I suppose that's not quite possible. (I'm not sure though) Considering that python dynamically defined functions are not even compiled, thus there's virtually no way to be run in C++ directly. Yet boost.python has boost::python::call as a wrapper.

Comment: @YiFei yup, I've been calling python functions just fine from C++ with boost::python::call. Sounds like you think that this cannot be done with Cython?

Comment: Pretty much, the error traceback you posted seems like it's not supported yet in Cython (I know little about Cython). But I think you can have a specialized invoke function on Python function and wait for Cython to support them:)

Comment: There isn't really a simple solution. You can do it if you're prepared to write a small wrapper yourself, or if you keep the boost dependency for this bit (and you can quite happily mix boost and Cython in this way)

Comment: Thanks @DavidW your answer looks like exactly what I'm looking for.